# How to set audio speed to 0.3 in Ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to set the audio and video speed to 0.3x. I can set the video speed but can't set the audio speed to 0.3x. Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf "setpts=PTS/0.3" -r 50 -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 1500k -af "atempo=0.3" output.mp4
```

It says:

```
Value 0.300000 for parameter 'tempo' out of range [0.5 - 100]
```

Is there a workaround? Any help will be appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use atempo + atempo:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf "setpts=PTS/0.3" -r 50 -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 1500k -af "atempo=0.6,atempo=0.5" output.mp4
```

Or use the [rubberband filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband) for a better sounding output.

Or use the standalone `rubberband` tool:

```
rubberband -t 3 input.wav output.wav
```